# How to call TYPO3 plugin when normal page renders

Tags: php, plugins, typo3

Well, I am developing a plugin a and I need to display some stuff from my plugin when TYPO3 page load. 
Is there some function how to hook action, like in WordPress when page loads than plugin will execute some controller method? Then this controller will produce some output a HTML, which I would like to dispaly in frontend page. Specially I would like display custom script in the head. So the script should be like this `<head>...<script>my content</script>...</head>`

Comment: making downvotes doesnt help me to solve this problem

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question could certainly benefit from further details in order to illustrate the issue better...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Render your own content? Modify already existing content? Something else entirely? Please describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: ok, I updated info.

Comment: If you want to get specific answers, your question should be that specific as well - what do you want to achieve, what kind of domain model (if any) are you dealing with? Displaying "some stuff" is very, very vague...

Comment: ok I added more concrete spec

Answer (score 3):

Ok, what you probably want to do is to develop a so-called TYPO3 extension - that's what plugins/add-ons are called in TYPO3 (which is the term you will likely find google results for).

To get started fast you can try the TYPO3 extension builder (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/) - which can generate a skeleton extension for you.

For more information you can also have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html which explains the concepts in far more detail.

Additional information is available in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/Index.html

Answer (score 2):

in TYPO3 there is something named plugins, but you should differ to the meaning in other context.
first TYPO3 is a CMS which content is structured in a hierarchical tree of pages. These pages are the basis for navigation. and each page contains individual contentelmenents (CE).
As Susi already told: add ons to TYPO3 are in general 'extensions' which could extend(!) the functinality of TYPO3 in different ways. one way is the definition of (TYPO3-)Plugins. These are special ContentElements which enable to show special information.
While normal CEs have all the information what to show in the record (e.g. Text & Image), plugins can be more flexible.
typical examples are: show a list of records OR one record in detail.
These Plugins can be controlled with typoscript or the plugin-CE could have additional fields to hold information what to display.

For detailed information how a plugin is defined consult the links given by Susi.
And be aware: for security reasons it is not possible to just execute a plain PHP file to echo any output. You need to register your plugin using the API, build your output as string and return the generated HTML as string to the calling function. For beginners the ExtensionBuilder will help you to generate a well formed extension which uses the API to register and output your data.

Answer (score -2):

OK guys, thanks for your answers, but it was not very concrete. I found this solution, is not the best one, **but it works**! If anybody has better please share.

At first, you have to make a file for the class which will be called from the hook at location `/your-plugin-name/Classes/class.tx_contenthook.php`. Filename have to have this pattern `class.tx_yourname.php` Inside we will have a code with one method which will be called by the hook.

```
class tx_contenthook {

    function displayContent(&$params, &$that){

       //content of page from param
       $content = $params['pObj']->content;

       //your content
       $inject = '4747474747';

        // inject content on 
       $content = str_replace('</body>', $inject. '</body>', $content);

       // save
       $params['pObj']->content = $content;
       }
}
```

And next, we have to call it on the hook. So Let's go to `/your-plugin-name/ext_localconf.php` and add there these two lines, which makes a magic and handles also caching.

```
// hook is called after caching
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['contentPostProc-output'][] = 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Classes/class.tx_contenthook.php:&tx_contenthook->displayContent';


// hook is called before caching
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['contentPostProc-all'][] = 'EXT:'. $_EXTKEY .'/Classes/class.tx_contenthook.php:&tx_contenthook->displayContent';
```

I hope this will help those who struggling with typo3.

Comment: Sorry, but that‘s not a good way to add contents. You‘re misusing those hooks made for post processing of existing content. It‘s a quick fix bypassing major TYPO3 patterns and will cause you maintenance troubles.

Comment: @undko if you have better solution please be free to share. I am looking for  a better solution.  Thanks

Comment: This answer is wrong in many aspects and violates the regular rendering flow in TYPO3. Proper documentation on building *extensions* (that's how plugins are called in TYPO3) are mentioned in this thread already.

Comment: Maybe it violates whatever, i dont care, but it works! I you have a better solution, please share an concreate example how can I put an content in "the proper way". Thanks

Comment: Guys, I tried this code what @BjørsonÅlmer added, and it **actually works**. I have to include some dynamic script in the header tag, and this solution was only one working.

Comment: In the case that somebody doesn't know what is the dynamic script, I will explain. In this case, dynamic javascript script is some kind generated by PHP with values special for the concrete website.